# Need step by step procedure of partitioning hard disk for dual boot

Tags: partitioning

I already have Ubuntu 14.04 installed and would like to install Windows 7 Ultimate as dual boot. My HDD is 1TB Gigabyte F2A55M-DS2. How can I partition my hard drive in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prepare hard drive for dual boot is to have one partition for Windows and one partition for Ubuntu. Forget about obsolete advices of having separate `/home` partition, separate `D:` partition for data etc. Such approach causes more trouble than benefit.

In your setup, **the easiest and most fault-proof method would be to do fresh installation of Windows 7 on whole drive and then install Ubuntu and let the installer shrink the Windows 7 partition**. Ubuntu installer have option of install alongside Windows 7 and does it pretty well.

If You need more details, please read [Dual Boot Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Partitions) article in official Ubuntu documentation.

**PS**

Keep in mind, that Windows 7 by default also creates hidden, small (100MB) partition in the beginning of the drive. Ubuntu will also need additional partition for swap area. This is nothing to worry about. Just install Windows 7 on whole drive, and then let Ubuntu installer automatically do the rest.